# Double linked list, functions pointer does not return by value in C?

Tags: c

The function below (in C) is made to delete parts of a double linked list
(double linked list = a list that points back and forth).
deleting from the middle of the linked list (the bottom of this function) works as expected (I don't have to return new as the list is automatically updated when function terminates)

however, when deleting from the start of the list or end of the list (the top and middle parts of this function) this function requires me to return new... which baffles me because passing a function via pointer is passing by value therefore shouldn't the list passed (named new in this function) update automatically

(IF OTHER PREVIOUS CODE IS REQUIRED TO ANSWER LET ME KNOW I JUST WANTED TO PINPOINT THE AREA THAT CONFUSED ME)

```
node *delete(int x, node *new)
{
    node *del = new;
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        del = del -> next;
    }

    // MEANING ITS THE FIRST ELEMENT OF THE LIST
    if (del -> before == NULL)
    {
    
        // WE WANT TO MAKE DEL POINT TO DEL -> NEXT
        // THEN WE WANT TO SET A POINTER TO DEL -> BEFORE 
        // THEN WE WANT TO SET DEL -> BEFORE TO NULL 
        // THEN WE WANT TO FREE THE NEW VARIABLE

        del = del -> next;
        node *rem = del -> before;
        del -> before = NULL;
        new = del;
        free(rem);
        return new;
    
    } 

    // MEANING ITS THE LAST ELEMENT OF THE LIST
    else if (del -> next == NULL)
    {
        // WE WANT TO SET DEL TO DEL -> BEFORE 
        // THEN WE WANT TO MAKE A NODE POINTING TO DEL -> NEXT
        // THEN WE WANT TO MAKE DEL -> NEXT NULL
        // THEN WE WANT TO FREE THE CREATED NODE 

        del = del -> before;
        node *rem = del -> next;
        del -> next = NULL;
        free(rem);
        return new;
    }

    // MEANING THE MIDDLE OF THE LIST
    else
    {
        del -> before -> next = del -> before -> next -> next;
        del -> next -> before = del -> next -> before -> before;
        free(del);
        return new;
    }

}
```

PROBLEM UNRESOLVED ?

Comment: Even in the very beginning of the function this code     for(int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        del = del -> next;
    } can invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: The function entirely should be rewritten. For example this code snippet del = del -> next;
        node *rem = del -> before;
        del -> before = NULL; also can invoke undefined behavior. That is the function is full of bugs.

Comment: x is the xth element in the list that needs to be removed... and yes new is the list... this function works but only by returning new

Comment: Why is that snippet buggy ? I'm setting del -> next because I want to keep the next part and im setting a new variable *rem to the before bit as I want to be able to free it once ive set new = del as ive used malloc in main

Comment: del->next can be a null pointer. So the next expression del->before invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: I understand what you're saying but I've prevented this undefined behaviour in main to ensure x is not bellow or above a specific value, therefore the pointer -> next in that situation can't be NULL

Comment: You nothing prevented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add some checks :) and simplify the code

```
node* delete(size_t x, node* head)
{
    node *del = head;

    for(size_t i = 0; del && i < x; i++)
    {
        del = del -> next;
    }

    if(del)
    {
        if (del -> before == NULL)
        {
            head = del -> next;
            if ( head ) head->before = NULL;
        } 

        else if (del -> next == NULL)
        {
            del -> before -> next = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            del -> before -> next = del -> next;
            del -> next -> before = del -> before;
        }
        free(del);
    }
    return head;
}
```

Comment: This code snippet         if (del -> before == NULL)
        {
            head = del -> next;
        }  contains a bug.

Comment: This function works great and is much better written than mine so thank you for the insight... the only thing is, my original question, "why do I need to return a pointer in a function when a pointer is passed by value in the function" remains.   if I set the return to void the end bit of the function works and I don't need to return anything, but if im cutting from the start or end (the first two parts of the function) I need to return a node* to update my original list

Comment: @rowley The pointer in the caller still points to the original head of the list. If that has been deleted, you need a pointer to the new head.

Comment: okay I think I get what you're saying ... so when I passed the "head" through in the function, even though the "head" was altered in the function, the original was not altered ?

Comment: @rowley no, he's saying that the original might have been deleted during the call, and you need to update it on the caller's side. in other words, if it's been deleted, using the original will cause segmentation faults and UB.